# is there a 'smooth unique' version in gnuplot that doesn't connect the points with line segments?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file in which I have multiple values of y for the same x. I want to average over y for the same x and then place that average as a point at x in the graph. I want to do exactly what 'smooth unique' does but without connecting the points with line segments.
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: That has nothing to do with smoothing and is only a matter of the plotting style: `plot "file" smooth unique with points`

Comment: @Christoph it can be perhaps a bit "confusing" that the default style for `smooth unique` or `smooth cumulative` is `with lines` while for `smooth frequency` it is not...

Comment: @ewcz That is quite strange, I wasn't aware of that. I would consider this a bug

Comment: smooth unique with points does the trick